# Adding Custom style for Pivot table epplus

Tags: pivot-table, epplus

Hi i have successfully  created a pivot table using EPPlus and i have requirement to change the default color style in pivot table ,how can i achieve this in epplus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the TableStyle of the pivot table like this. Here `Dark2` is chosen, but there's plenty to choose from.

```
pivotTable.TableStyle = OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Dark2;
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i know this but i would like to know how to add Custom style which i can customize ... is this possible ?

Comment: @UnknownX have a look at the [EPPlus GitHub page](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Formatting-and-styling) for the `CreateNamedStyle` function, mentioned in the last bit of code on that page. This is the closest I have been able to find, that may be usefull for what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks  ,Thats what im looking for .. :))